# JSON Files as parameter input using Forge Design Automation

Tags: autodesk-designautomation

Looking at the documentation at the Autodesk Forge site, I noticed I can provide JSON information to a Design Automation Activity.  My question is: how would I reference the JSON information in a bundled AutoCAD application. Is there a filename reference in the shown -curl example I'm not seeing or understand? What am I not getting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You reference JSON like any other input: by its filename. The server will download your json the same way it downloads DWG/RVT etc. The file will be located in the working directory of the worker process.

Comment: Well, I assumed that, but I didn't recognize what the actual filename was.

Answer (score 1):

Found my answer:  Below is the example in the documentation:

```
curl -X POST \
  https://developer.api.autodesk.com/da/us-east/v3/workitems \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -H 'Authorization: Bearer YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN' \
  -d '{
          "activityId": "YOUR_NICKNAME.CountItActivity+test",
          "arguments": {
            "rvtFile": {
              "url": "https://s3.amazonaws.com/revitio-dev/test-data/CountIt.rvt"
            },
            "countItParams": {
              "url": "data:application/json,{'walls': false, 'floors': true, 'doors': true, 'windows': true}"
            },
            "result": {
              "verb": "put",
              "url": "SIGNED_URL_TO_RESULT"
            }
          }
      }'
```

countItParams is the name of the created .json file and is placed in the same folder as the input files.  https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/design.automation-csharp-revit.local.debug.tool

You can later access the file in your bundled application by referencing the current directory.

Sorry about answering my own question.  I feel like I'm cheating. lol

Comment: `"countItParams": {
              "url": "data:application/json,{'walls': false, 'floors': true, 'doors': true, 'windows': true}"
            }` This is only recommend if you have less number of parameters, if the JSON parameter are more, you need put the JSON file in a storage box and provide its url like any other input object, to avoid  `HTTP 413 Payload Too Large`

Comment: First things, first.  How I do structure this as a new parameter argument in C#?

Comment: Correction:  This doesn't go in the Activity, it goes in the workitem.  { "inputJson", new XrefTreeArgument() {Verb= Verb.Put, LocalName = "parameters.json", Url = "data:application/json,{'ProtoCycle':" + protocycle} }  where protocycle is an argument to my method.  Does this look correct?

Comment: *exhale*  So, there has to be a matching dictionary parameter in the Activity:  Does this look right?  { "inputJson", new Parameter() { LocalName = "parameters.json", Required = true} }.  Is there a Verb I should use?  The WorkItem looks like this:  { "inputJson", new XrefTreeArgument() { LocalName = "parameters.json", Url = "data:application/json,{'ProtoCycle':" + protocycle} }.  Once again, I removed the verb.

Comment: Hi,
First ,you need to create a compatible class structure in your C# refer https://github.com/KeanW/Jigsawify/blob/43c8ddabb75f1f2a8b1649c3552584b25c932594/management/ClientV3/App.cs#L31,
second, you need to pass it as serializedJson, refer https://github.com/KeanW/Jigsawify/blob/43c8ddabb75f1f2a8b1649c3552584b25c932594/management/ClientV3/App.cs#L146, the verb should `get`, or leave it blank, by default it assumes `get`

Comment: Thank you Mr. Moogala.  Looking at my log file, that seems to have done the trick.  One last question, if I may: Am I the only that's disappointed in the documentation.  I see it getting better from V1 to V2 to V3, but still......

Comment: Sorry!, please do ask as many as questions as possible, however we are trying our best to update documentation.

Comment: So, here's my followup, starting with my Activity:
{ "inputJson", new Parameter() { Verb= Verb.Get, LocalName = "parameters.json", Required = true} }. 
Here's my WorkItem: { "inputJson", new XrefTreeArgument() { LocalName = "parameters.json", Url = $"data:application/json,{JsonConvert.SerializeObject(new Parameters{ PDFProtoCycle = protocycle})}"} }. 
And here's my class I'm serializing against:public class Parameters { public string PDFProtoCycle { get; set; } }